# Upload de arquivo dentro da pasta webapp

Tags: java, upload, jersey

Tenho uma API Rest com Jersey onde faço o upload de arquivos. Se eu defino o caminho pra qualquer outro lugar, ex: `C:\\uploads` funciona, mas gostaria de salvar esses arquivos dentro de um diretório em webapp:

Atualmente faço dessa forma:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/anexoCliente")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws IOException {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "C:/uploads/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Esse é o diretório em que quero salvar os arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo definir o caminho correto para esse diretório?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa obter o ServletContext para chamar o método `getRealPath`:

```
String caminho = getServletContext().getRealPath("webapp/uploads/");
File file = new File(caminho);
String caminhoCompleto = file.getCanonicalPath();
```

Como você está usando uma API Rest e Jersey, você provavelmente vai conseguir pegar o ServletContext no serviço:

```
@Context
ServletContext context;
```

Então você poderá chamar o equivalente, `context.getRealPath()`.